# Morphism, functional equations and bijection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, analysis, functional-equations, morphism

I've got a question about something. We consider $\mathbb{T}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} 
 \; | \; |z|=1 \}$, and :

$car(\mathbb{R}) = \{ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{T} \; | \; f$ continuous and $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} \; f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \}$

We have already show that $(1)$ $\forall \epsilon > 0 \; f(x)=g(x)$ on $]-\epsilon;\epsilon[$, then $f=g$, and also : if $f : ]-1;1[ \rightarrow ]-1;1[$ is continuous and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for $x,y \in ]-1;1[$ such as $x+y \in ]-1;1[$, then $f(x)=cx$ for $x \in ]-1;1[$, where $c = 4f(\frac{1}{4})$.

Now, I want to show that : $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow car(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $u \rightarrow \hat{u}$ where $\hat{u}(x) = e^{iux}$ is a bijection.

This is what I did :

Let's $f \in car(\mathbb{R})$ which verify the condition wanted. Then, $f(x) = e^{iu(x)}$ for a certain function $u$. Now, I consider $arg : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by :

$arg(x) = u(x) \; $(mod)$\; (2\pi)$ and $arg(x) \in [0;2\pi[$ for all $x$. Then, from $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, we can show that : $arg(x+y)=arg(x)+arg(y)$, and $arg$ is also continuous. Then, I wanted to consider the restriction of $arg$ on $]-1;1[$, and by the result $(1)$, we have for all $x \in ]-1;1[$ : $arg(x) = cx$, $c = 4arg(\frac{1}{4})$. Then, $u = c$ and $\hat{u} = f$ on $]-1;1[$, and then, again by $(1)$, $\hat{u}=f$. The only problem is that the hypothesis of $(1)$ implies that we should have $arg(]-1;1[) \subseteq ]-1;1[$, which is not necessarily true.

But in my proof of $(1)$, I don't use anywhere that $f(]-1;1[) \subseteq ]-1;1[$, so I don't know if it's my proof which is wrong or if it's not a condition which is needed.

Someone to help ? :)

Comment: Are statements (1) and (2) part of your plan for how to prove this? Or are they hints from elsewhere?  They don't seem to me to lead to an elegant way to prove that any continuous homomorphism $f$ from the additive group $\Bbb{R}$ to the multiplicative group $S^1$ (which you call $\Bbb{T}$) has the form $x \mapsto e^{uix}$ for some unique $u$ in $\Bbb{R}$). And this does have an easy(ish) and elegant proof.

Comment: Actually it's the questions just before, so I thought I had to use them.

Comment: I see. The elegant proof I have in mind first investigates $f$ on the integers, then on the rationals using its algebraic properties and then concludes the desired identity by continuity.

Comment: Okay ! I'll try to do that, and if I don't succeed to do that, I will write here what I did. Thank you !